# My bad answer gave me enough rep to upvote the correct one. If I delete it, does that poster lose credit for my vote?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, deleted-answers

I wrote an answer to my own question which I realize isn't helpful. I'd like to delete it but it gave me enough reputation points to vote up the right answer. If I delete and lose those points, does she lose the points she gained from my up vote?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, votes are not retracted if you end up falling below the privilege threshold. You just won't be able to cast any *new* votes until you get above that threshold again.